# php: two client to share server user defined variable

Tags: javascript, php

GOAL: create kitchen and front desk can notify each other.

**Q:** how do i create php variable that can be read and set from kitchen and front desk. Let say the variable is ***vStatus***. so the plan is when the front desk create order then ***vStatus = 'kitchen1'***, and when kitchen notify order is ready then ***vStatus='frontdesk1'***.

on each other i create timer function to monitor the vstatus:

- on front desk when ***vstatus='frontdesk1'***  then page is refreshed, and set ***vstatus=''***. so the timer function on front desk side cycle continue until ***vstatus=frondesk1***.
- on kitchen when ***vstatus='kitchen1'*** the kitchen page is refreshed and set ***vstatus=''*** and timer function on kitchen side cycle until ***vstatus='kitchen1'***

the hardware setup is like this:

- front desk :apache web server, web browser
- kitchen : web browser

Comment: You can use SQL (or any other DB) or Filesystem. The major reliability it's in a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot share a PHP variable between separate requests - that would be a terrible thing from security point of view.

What you are looking for is a storage - some place outside of the php process that would persist your value even when the request processing (php execution) ends.

There are numerous options available for that, but here's a few most common and easiest to setup/implement:

- [*Files*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) - e.g. at the beginning of the execution [read the value from file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and when the value changes, [write the new value to the file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) overwriting the old value
- *Key-Value store* (e.g. [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or [Redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis)) - You would need to install the memcached/redis server that would run as independent system process. Then you would connect to it and [read the value](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.get.php) and [write the value](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php) when it changes. (Note these can be configured to be persistent or non-persistent storages, see next point or explanation)
- [*APC cache*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php) - it's a special case of key-value store which works as a PHP extension rather than external service. The idea is still [reading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-store.php)/[writing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-fetch.php) the value stored in it. Note that this is not a persistent storage, meaning that when apache or php-fpm process is restarted the cache will be cleared and the value lost.
- [*Database*](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php) (e.g. [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php)). Again, you would have to install the database server and do some reading on how to use them.

There are certainly more options, but these are something to start with.

Comment: thank you very much, i think to start with Files approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL to store that variable on server and AJAX requests to if you want to check the value in any set interval

Comment: so you think the best approach is: on javascript timer function i always create xmlhttp request to: let say vstatus.php.